# Hotkey to open TFS Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, hotkeys, source-control-explorer

Currently I have to open Team Explorer and click on `Source Control Explorer` as below snapshot.

I do this very often and need a hotkey for that.

What is it then?

[image]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try with below step:

Go to **Options** of **Tools** menu

[image: Description]

1. Select the **Keyboard** from Environment
2. Select *View.TfsSourceControlExplorer* from **Show commands containing:**. You can type View.TFS in the textbox to filter the list.
3. Enter your hotkey in Press shorcut keys => click on **Assign**

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry for being nitpicky here, but I think the answer is "There is no built-in shortcut to 'Souce Control Explorer'" isn't it? You can create a shortcut for anything in VS but this is not the correct answer here. It would be a nice workaround obviously. Could you perhaps reword the answer to reflect that (if you agree with me that is)?

Answer (score 53):

According to [a comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/06/team-explorer-2012-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx#10498874) that I found in the site that [@Adarsh mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21132954/1704355), **Alt+V,E,S** will open the **Source Control Explorer**. It's a couple extra keystrokes but it works for me!

Comment: It would be nice to have a shortcut to close it as well though. Any ideas?

Comment: Careful use of Ctrl+F4?

Answer (score 10):

You can use **Ctrl+0,P** to open the **Pending Changes** Window.

You can find all the shortcuts for team Explorer on this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/06/team-explorer-2012-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx

**Update:**

In **Visual Studio 2013** `Ctrl+0,P` doesn't seem to work to open **Pending Changes**, but you can use `Alt-V,E,H` or configure a custom shortcut in the menu `Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard`.

Comment: I'm not looking for Pending Changes. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share another alternative I learned. One could set an alias in VS Command Window and launch it from there.

```
alias sce View.TfsSourceControlExplorer
```

note- 'sce' is an alias of your choice. I generally abbreviate. Obvious but having a pattern will be helpful if you have many of these.

Steps:

1. Open command window (ctrl+alt+A)
2. Set the alias (the statement shown
   above)
3. Next time you need to launch the Source Control Explorer,
   switch/launch command window and type your alias name. 'sce' in the
   above example.

Answer (score 2):

**Alt+V,E,S** works for me even in VS 2015

In case you like to see more shortcuts, please visit this site
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com

Answer (score 1):

IN VS 2015
Toolbar=>Team=> Manage Connections =>(window like solution explorer will open on right side) Team Explorer- Connect=> Beneath the home symbol ==> Click "Connect"=>Click "Source Control Explorer"