# How to set hotkey of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Do you know how can i change the hot key in VS?

Example: I want to extract function of class into interface, default VS use Ctrl + Shirt + R. I want to change to Ctrl + Shirt + I

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx

Comment: you can find the thread at 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131024/hotkey-to-open-tfs-source-control-explorer-in-visual-studio-2012/21134549#21134549

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Mark Hall. I using VS 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hot Key that you have given is mapped on my Installation to `Debug.RefreshWindowsapp`, Loooking at the bindings there is a `Refactor.ExtractInterface` that on my computer is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. You can locate it by going to Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard, Once you get there you can edit the hotkey to your liking, you will have to change the bindings that are in conflict with what you are trying to use.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, It is what I need

Comment: @TrieuH Glad to be of help, I had to guess at the actual function your were wanting.